# if statement based on serial data (processing)

Tags: button, if-statement, arduino, processing

I have an Arduino that sends serial data to Processing.  Things like "3High", "3Low", etc...

I want processing to constantly read the data and use if statements to trigger events.  EG, if it sees the string "4High", it will do something.

This is what I have but can't figure out the If Statements...

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String val;     // Data received from the serial port

void setup() 
{
    size(600, 600);
// Open whatever port is the one you're using.
String portName = Serial.list()[1]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600); 
}

void draw()
{
  if ( myPort.available() > 0) 
  {  // If data is available,
  val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');         // read it and store it in val
  } 
println(val); //print it out in the console



  if (val == "3High"){
    fill(255,200,200);
    ellipse(60,20,100,100);
  }
  if (val == "3Low"){
    fill(200);
    ellipse(250, 250, 100, 100);    
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Processing is Java based language and the correct way to compare two Strings is by using `equals()` function. For more information about strings read [here](http://processing.org/reference/String.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

```java
if (val.equals("4High")) {
  println("Yes");
}
```

To read serial data you should consider using `serialEvent`find more information and example [here](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/serialEvent_.html) and for different string values just use separate `if` statements like in you example.

Comment: Just to add that the preferred style for comparison to `String` literals is `Literal.equals(...)`, in this case `"4High".equals(val)`.